# Slide galeria uma imagem de cada vez com BxSlider

Tags: jquery, script, bxslider

Estou tentando criar galeria de slide com http://bxslider.com/ Gostaria que a galeria passasse uma imagem de cada vez e não um grupo de imagens.

Exemplo que estou usando mas que gostaria de MUDAR : http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-dynamic-number-slides)

Abaixo o código:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.bxslider').bxSlider({  
       minSlides: 3,
       maxSlides: 2,
       slideWidth: 170,
       slideMargin: 10});
     });
</script>
```

Lendo as opções de bxslider achei a opção getCurrentSlide que acho que poderia da certo mas não sei como introduzir no script acima :

```
example:
slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
var current = slider.getCurrentSlide();
```

Obrigada!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resposta a isso está no próprio código `jquery` que publicas-te na tua pergunta, e até está mencionado na **[página de exemplos](http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-dynamic-number-slides)** do link que adicionas-te, logo após o código HTML dessa página de exemplos.

`minSlides` **> significa:** número mínimo de slides a serem apresentados
`maxSlides` **> significa:** número máximo de slides a serem apresentados

Estes parâmetros existem para mostrar **menos** ou **mais** slides conforme o tamanho da tela do ecrã dependendo do valor que lhes aplicares, que neste caso por padrão são:

```
minSlides: 2,
maxSlides: 3,
```

Ou seja em ecrãs pequenos, serão apresentados apenas 2 slides de cada vez, enquanto em ecrãs de maiores dimensões serão apresentados 3 slides. Podes testar isso **[neste exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npbvc4wm/)** que criei, onde já modifiquei o código para mostrar apenas 1 slide de cada vez.

Para mostrar apenas 1 slide de cada vez, tens que modificar o código jQuery para o seguinte:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    minSlides: 1,     // mínimo de slides
    maxSlides: 1,     // máximo de slides
    slideWidth: 170,  // largura do slide
    slideMargin: 10   // margem do slide
});
```

No código acima eu comentei o que este parâmetros fazem, mas depois quando estiveres a implementar o código na tua plataforma podes removê-los, pois os comentários estão ali só para te orientar e dar uma noção do que estes fazem.